# Python whois like function

Tags: python-3.x

Okay so I have a file called 'whois.txt' which contains

```
 ["96363612", "@a2743, coil, charge"]
 ["12101258", "@a0272, climate, vault"]
 ["83157521", "sith"]
 ["33907120", "@a1321, missile, wired"]
 ["55553768", "@a2722, legal, illegal"]
 ["22686400", "@a5619, mindless, @a5637, bank"]
 ["97436430", "jedi, @a5770, charge, lantern, @a9491, legal"]
 ["91645905", "sith"]
 ["89514799", "lantern, @a2563, @a2693"]
 ["19658307", "Umbrechu"]
 ["56112504", "@a0473, lantern, kryptonian"]
 ["12195491", "riyoken"]
 ["53281943", "@a5135, gateway, jedi"]
 ["76515035", "@a4023, gateway, wired"]
 ["79444876", "@a2716, loyalty"]
```

What I'm doing here is using json and using the first numbers as an ID and the accounts that are associated with the ID are linked by ', '. So using python I am using this code to try to get all the accounts that are associated

```
 def getWhois(self):
    x = []
    f = open('whois.txt','r')
    for line in f.readlines():
        rid,names = json.loads(line.strip())
        x.append([rid,names])
    return x
 def recvWhois(self,user):
    returned = self.getWhois()
    x = []
    for data in returned:
        rid,names = data[0],data[1]
        if user in names:
            x.append(names)
            matches = list(set(', '.join(x).split(', ')))
    return matches
```

So what that is doing is getting the matches of a user you are searching but I want to search the users in those matches also, I have done this but It feels Like I would have to do this an infinite amount of times of researching matches that are pulled so if I were to do self.recvWhois('missile') It would pull "['missile', 'wired', '@a1321']" I would then try to search all of those accounts to link more, and by now you probably see my problem because I would have to do that x amount of times depending on how many matches there are linked to the previous matched accounts If any of you have a solution to my problem it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First i would suggest to maintain an index for searching. You could use a search engine but a python map can also serve as a poor man's search engine. So idea is to have an inverted index where the usernames points to records to which they belong. For searching all linked accounts you can write a *memoized* recursive function which will cut down the infinite recursive paths. Also in case you have large no. of records you can limit recursion to a predefined maximum level.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to tell what you are trying to do, but I think you are making it too complicated. Your data structure lends itself to a dictionary. Why not load it using `rid` as the key and `names` as the values?